# create key-value pair Borland C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I'm trying create some Dictionary in Borland 2010 C++.

```
TDictionary__2<AnsiString, AnsiString> *d = new TDictionary__2<AnsiString, AnsiString>();
```

I got error:
[BCC32 Error] Generics.collections.hpp(542): E2347 Parameter mismatch in read access specifier of property Items

what I do wrong?

Comment: Every time I see a question that mentions a Borland compiler I have flashbacks.  Sitting in a coffee shop with my 25 lb "laptop" trying to teach myself C++...

Comment: `some_type* some_variable = new some_type();` **Stop programming as in Java**

Comment: @Manu343726: in this case, `TDictionary` derives from `TObject`, which is implemented in Delphi Pascal and cannot be allocated on the stack, so the use of `new` is required. That is a limitation of C++Builder's interaction with the Delphi RTL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++Builder can only consume instances of Delphi-based Generics types, like `TDictionary`, that originate from Delphi code.  Unfortunately, it cannot instantiate Delphi-based Generics types.  If you are not trying to interact with Delphi code, then you should use the STL's `std::map` class instead:

```
#include <map>

std::map<AnsiString, AnsiString> d;
```